# TIKZ3D - Drawing arc with superimposed label

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, tikz-3d

I would like to receive some help from you. I've been able to add the label for a vector in the middle of the arrow itself in tikz3d by using a command like

```
\tdplotsetcoord{Mp}{\rvm}{\phm}{\thm}
\path (O) -- node[sloped] (text) {$\bv{r}_{kj}(t)$} (Mp);
\draw[-latex,shorten >=3mm] (O) -- (text) -- (Mp);
```

[image]

However I would like to obtain the same with arcs. Given that I'm using the command
`\tdplotdrawarc[-latex]{(O)}{0.8}{0}{\thm}{anchor=north}{$\vth_k(t)$}` I cannot find a way to include it. Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,angles,quotes,positioning}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{110}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,tdplot_main_coords]
\definecolor{earth}{RGB}{0,128,0}
\definecolor{moon}{RGB}{119,136,153}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvm}{1.2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phm}{70}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thm}{150}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\draw[thick,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{${ I}$};
\draw[thick,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=north west]{${ J}$};
\draw[thick,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.2) node[anchor=south]{${ K}$};
% Earth
\tdplotsetcoord{Ep}{0}{0}{0}
% draw Moon position, theta, phi, RTN CS
\tdplotsetcoord{Mp}{\rvm}{\phm}{\thm}
\path (O) -- node[sloped] (text) {${r}_{kj}(t)$} (Mp);
\draw[-latex,shorten >=3mm] (O) -- (text) -- (Mp);
\draw[dashed,shorten >=-20pt ] (O) -- (Mpxy);
\tdplotdrawarc[-latex]{(O)}{0.8}{0}{\thm}{anchor=north}{$\vartheta_k(t)$}
\shade[ball color = earth] {(Ep)} circle (2.5pt);
\shade[ball color = moon] {(Mp)} circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A hach:  Repeat with `\tdplotdrawarc[draw=none]{(O)}{0.8}{0}{\thm}{shift={(-7pt,-3pt)}, inner sep=1pt, fill=white}{$\vartheta_k(t)$}` . -but at this stage, a normal node placed manually is even better.

Comment: Thank you, it works. However, your solution implies a "manual" tuning of shift values to accommodate changes in the vector definitions (e.g. \rvm). If there is an automatic solution it would be awesome! Thank you for you help anyway :)

Comment: Yes. I am afraid, there is no solution that does not involve hacking into the code. -it is not even possible not to have the label in the middle of the arc.